# Simple way to add/remove an additional CSS class on a standard ASP.NET web-forms control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a navigation menu as an ASP.NET web-forms user control (ASCX).
Each menu item can become active depending on the page the control is rendered at. The active state should be denoted with an additional CSS class named "`active`".
What item to become active is controlled from the code-behind file by setting to `true` one of these properties: `IsMenuItem1Active` or `IsMenuItem2Active`.

Now my question is: **How, based on the set property, can I modify the `CssClass` property of the corresponding menu item inside the view without doing any additional logic in code-behind?**

```
<div class="menu">
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="MenuItem1" CssClass="menu-item" NavigateUrl="~/">Menu item 1</asp:HyperLink>
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="MenuItem2" CssClass="menu-item" NavigateUrl="~/">Menu item 1</asp:HyperLink>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add the statement to add class in code behind its not big deal.

Comment: It is a big deal as I don't want to recompile the project if I just want to change a class name. That's the solely reason why the code-behind is separated from the view, so that design aspects could be changed without messing with the logic.

Comment: And here is the right answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990046/why-doesnt-binding-expression-work-with-c-sharp-expressions

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with the separation of design and logic, it would be better to control the CssClass value from code behind. Any design changes that you will need to make can be done through the CSS represented by the `active` class name you're adding.

If you absolutely *must* do this in the view, then you could use a bit of JavaScript:

```
<script>
var c = '<%= IsMenuItem1Active ? "menu-item active" : "menu-item" %>'
document.getElementById('<%= MenuItem1.ClientID %>').setAttribute('class', c);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code :

```
            <div class="menu">
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="MenuItem1" CssClass="menu-item" NavigateUrl="~/">Menu item 1</asp:HyperLink>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="MenuItem2" CssClass="menu-item" NavigateUrl="~/">Menu item 1</asp:HyperLink>
            </div>
            <%-- Change css here--%>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            <%if (IsMenuItem1Active == true)
             {%>
                document.getElementById("<%=MenuItem1.ClientID%>").className += " active";
           <%}
            else if (IsMenuItem2Active == true)
            {%>
                document.getElementById("<%=MenuItem2.ClientID%>").className += " active";
           <%}%>
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two ways to do it. One way is by using javascript. The second way is by using asp.net lifecycle hook functions for the specific control.

**First option:**
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript), you could add a css class to a specific element using this:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " MyClass";
```

This call should be made in the `onLoad` function which is called just before the HTML DOM is created.

**Second option:**
According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.ASPX) article describing the ASP.NET lifecycle, you could use the `PreRender` function in order to add the css class.

Hope I helped!