# Why doesn't binding expression work with C# expressions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

The following code compiles, but doesn't work. As far as I know data-binding expressions allow any valid C# code in them. So what am I doing wrong here?

```
<asp:Panel CssClass='<%# ("my-class") %>' runat="server" ID="myPannel">
   Blah
</asp:Panel>

<% this.myPannel.DataBind(); %>
```

I am not getting any errors. It just doesn't render the class attribute whatsoever. I tried without the parenthesis with the same bad luck.

Please note, I need an expression to be evaluated in CssClass attribute and I am expecting the result of that expression to be assigned to the class attribute. This is why I emphasized this by enclosing the string into parenthesis.

Comment: what error are you getting. I would remove the () in the css class assignment. Also,It doesn't need server tags since it's already a hard coded constant

Comment: Shouldn't it be ``<%= "my-class" %>``?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. It just doesn't render the class attribute whatsoever. I tried without the parenthesis with the same bad luck.

Comment: Did you try ``=`` instead of ``#``?

Comment: @acfrancis, with `=` it renders like this: `<div class="&lt;%= &quot; (my-class) &quot;%>">Blah</div>`

Comment: OK, try ``CssClass=<%= "my-class" %>`` (with equals instead of hash, no parentheses and no single quotes)

Comment: Any databinding expression is evaluated when Databind is called in the control itself or any parent control. When for example a list control (Repeater, GridView,...) creates a new item or row, it calls the Databind after adding it in its collection and setting the dataitem, so all expressions are evaluated at the right time. The <%= evaluates on page rendering stage, just tοο late ... and is invalid for this use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script runat="server">
        protected void 
            Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.myPannel.DataBind();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel CssClass='<%# ("my-class") %>' 
            runat="server" 
            ID="myPannel">
            Blah
        </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Or just switch the order of your inline code snippets:

```
<body>
    <% this.myPannel.DataBind(); %>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel CssClass='<%# ("my-class") %>'
            runat="server"
            ID="myPannel">
            Blah
        </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
```

Or simply use:

```
<% this.myPannel.CssClass = "my-class";%>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel
        runat="server"
        ID="myPannel">
        Blah
    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

In all three cases, you have to make sure that the control property is updated **before** the actual inline code of the control is being processed in the page's life cycle.